# only saving last item while saving in core data swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

With this function I want to add attributes in [core-data](/questions/tagged/core-data) entity but it saves only last item repeatedly.

what am I doing wrong?

```
 func SetFeaturedValues(Array : NSArray){
        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FeaturedJob",
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let FeaturedJob = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                      insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    print("array is \(Array)")
    for i in Array{
        if let rowData :NSDictionary = i as? NSDictionary{
            FeaturedJob.setValue(rowData["company"], forKey: "company")
            FeaturedJob.setValue(rowData["city"], forKey: "city")
            FeaturedJob.setValue(rowData["id"], forKey: "id")
            FeaturedJob.setValue(rowData["user_logo"], forKey: "user_logo")
            FeaturedJob.setValue(rowData["title"], forKey: "title")



        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            self.Featured.append(FeaturedJob)
            print("featured job is \(FeaturedJob)")
            //                people.append(person)

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share a snap of your `core_data.model`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this could still do with some tidying up but...

What's going wrong is that you are creating only one single`NSManagedObject` instance called `FeaturedJob`. Every time you iterate through the array you append its value and save it. But its the same instance! That's why only one instance gets saved.

So put the line with let `let FeaturedJob = ...` inside the if block just before you start assigning values. That way you're going to get a new one each time.

PS: You are saving the context with every iteration. You probably only want to do that once at the end of the function.

Comment: thank you :), and i did't get ur last suggestion.

Comment: So, the last thing was that the managedContext.save call is inside the loop that is iterating through and adding the entities to the context. Every entity is getting individually saved. Saving is expensive, so just do it once at the end. Don't worry, the context will keep hold of the new entities in the meantime so you can save them all at once.

Comment: it is working fine now. but encountered another problem when i relaunch app i found no data in core data.